# What is $x^\bot$? Is $\zeta(\bot)=\bot$ for Riemann's zeta function $\zeta$ and wheel theory's $\bot$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponentiation, riemann-zeta, infinite-product, wheel-theory

### Background:

A [wheel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_theory) is an algebraic structure $(W,0,1,+,\cdot, /)$ where:

- $W$ is a set,
- $0,1\in W,$
- $+$ and $\cdot$ are binary operations,
- $/$ is a unary operation,

and

- $+,\cdot$ are associative, commutative, and with identities $0$ and $1$, respectively,
- $//x=x$,
- $/(xy)=/x/y$,
- $xz+yz=(x+y)z+0z$,
- $(x+yz)=x/y+z+0y$,
- $0\cdot 0=0$,
- $(x+0y)z=xz+0y$,
- $/(x+0y)=/x+0y$,
- $0/0+x=0/0$.

We denote $0/0$ by $\bot$.

The final axiom can be written as

$$\bot+x=\bot.$$

See

[What are the mathematical properties of ⊥ in wheel theory?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3003703/104041)

Therefore,

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i=\bot\tag{$\Sigma$}$$

is $\bot$ whenever $a_i=\bot$ for at least one $i\in\Bbb N$.

### The Question:

> Can we go any further than $(\Sigma)$? What is $x^\bot$? In particular, is $$\zeta(\bot)=\bot$$ for Riemann's zeta function?

### Thoughts:

Due to the argument in the question linked to, my intuition is that, yes, we can go further; for instance,

$$\prod_{i=1}^\infty a_i=\bot\tag{$\Pi$}$$

whenever $a_i=\bot$ for at least one $i\in\Bbb N$, where $\Pi$ is defined in the obvious manner; *but*

$$
\zeta(\bot)
:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1\cdot/(n^\bot)
$$

requires some notion of what $n^\bot$ means. I guess it should be

$$x^\bot=\bot.\tag{$\bot$}$$

But breaking this down:

$$
x^\bot =x^{0/0}
=x^{0\cdot /0}
=(x^0)^{/0}
=1^{/0},$$

which has me stumped. Should we *define*

$$1^{/0}:=\bot?\tag{1}$$

### Further Context:

This is just for fun. I don't think anything deep is going on here.

I have no formal training in wheel theory.

---

Please help :)

Comment: I don't understand your question. You are free to define whatever you want. Where is the problem?

Comment: @Somos I assume that the OP is interested in the question, "how do we define $x^{\bot}$ in a way that naturally aligns with ordinary, real number exponentiation, but is consistent with the principles of Wheel Theory?". But I think they might be jumping the gun a bit by asking about the zeta function. (How does convergence apply in WT?)

Comment: @Jam Then what precisely does "naturally follow ..." mean?

Comment: @Somos I mean that the definition in question would keep some essential characteristics when being generalized. For instance, in this case, we might want that the new WT exponentiation still satisfies $x^{a+b}=x^{a}\cdot x^{b}$ or some such identity, even at the sake of losing others. This is what we would hope for whenever generalizing. For instance, when we define $\sin z$ on $\mathbb{C}$, we define that the power series from $\mathbb{R}$ continues to hold. And that consistency and fluency is what I mean by a definition "naturally following/aligning".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some thoughts:

In order to define $x^\bot$, we need to define exponentiation on wheels. This isn't something we can do analogously to rings, because for a general ring $R$ there isn't some well-defined exponentiation $R\times R \rightarrow R$. Even if $R=\mathbb Q$ we're in trouble. I guess the wheel-ized version of $\mathbb R$ is $$
\mathbb R \cup\{/0,0/0\}
$$
analogous to how the wheel of fractions over $\mathbb Z$ is $\mathbb Q \cup\{/0,0/0\}$. Then we'd have the usual addition and multiplication and $/x = x^{-1}$ for $x\ne 0$, then for the extra stuff: $x + /0 = x\cdot/0 = /0$ for $x\notin\{/0,0/0\}$ and $x + 0/0 = x\cdot 0/0 = 0/0$ and $0\cdot /0= 0/0$.

To define exponentiation on $\mathbb{R}$, we usually start with the function $$
\exp(x) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}
$$
The standard proof that $\exp(x+y) = \exp(x)\exp(y)$ works just as well here. We have, of course, $$
\exp(/0) = /0 \text{ and }\exp(0/0) = 0/0
$$
Thus $\exp$ is a bijection from $\mathbb{R}\cup\{/0,0/0\}$ to $\mathbb{R}^+\cup\{/0,0/0\}$, so we have $\log : \mathbb{R}^+\cup\{/0,0/0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\cup\{/0,0/0\}$ is well defined. Thus we can define exponentiation $a^b$ with $a>0$ or $a\in\{/0,0/0\}$ by $$
a^b = \exp((\log a)b)
$$
from which we can see right away $a^{0/0}=0/0$ for any $a$, so as you suspect $\zeta(\bot) = \bot$.